# Check if a view is enabled or disabled

Tags: 7, views

How can I check from a custom module if a specific view is enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a view object, checking if the view is disabled just requires to check the value of `$view->disabled`; if it is `TRUE`, the view is disabled.

```
if (!$view->disabled) {
  // The view is enabled.
}
```

This method works independently from the view type, and it doesn't give false negatives when a module alters the output returned from a hook implemented by another module, which is what could happen with `hook_block_view()`, whose output could be altered by [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7.x).

To get a view object, you can use [`views_get_view($name)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7.x-3.x), which is the function used also from [`views_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_block_view/7.x-3.x).

```
if ($view = views_get_view($name)) {
  if ($view->access($display_id)) {
    $view->set_display($display_id);
    if (isset($view->display_handler)) {
      $output = $view->display_handler->view_special_blocks($type);
      // Before returning the block output, convert it to a renderable
      // array with contextual links.
      views_add_block_contextual_links($output, $view, $display_id, 'special_block_' . $type);
      $view->destroy();
      return $output;
    }
  }
  $view->destroy();
}
```

If you also need to know if the currently logged-in user has access to the view (i.e. the user can see the view output), you need also to call `$view->access($display_id)`, where `$display_id` can be easily get from the delta of the block with `list($nothing, $type, $name, $display_id) = explode('-', $delta);`.

The code you need to use, in the case of just checking if the view is enabled is similar to the following.

```
$view = views_get_view($name);
// Always check the value returned from views_get_view(), since it can return NULL.
if (!empty($view) && $view->disabled) {
  // The view exists and it is enabled.
}
```

In the case you need to check the currently logged-in user has access to the view, the code should be similar to the following one.

```
$view = views_get_view($name);
// Always check the value returned from views_get_view(), since it can return NULL.
if (!empty($view) && $view->access($display_id)) {
  // The view exists and the user has access to it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it with `module_invoke()`.

```
$block = module_invoke('views','block_view','-exp-machinenameoftheview-page');
if (!empty($block)) {
  // The view is enabled.
}
else{
  // The view is disabled.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [views_get_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7.x-3.x) function to do this.

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
if ($view->disabled) {
  // Do something
}
```